# What is the difference with this and slicing?

Tags: python

https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-string/ Hey there, I'm doing reverse the string on leetcode and this is the solution.

```
def reverseString(self, s):
    """
    :type s: List[str]
    :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
    """
    s[:] = s[::-1]
```

The part that I'm not understanding is s[:]. Why do we need that? From what I was thinking, we could simply do:

```
s = s[::-1]
```

Not understanding this and hoping someone could guide me. Thank you!

Comment: Note the comments in the posted code “.. modify s in-place instead”. What *different thing* would happen with a normal assignment? Also note that `s` is a *list of strings* (and the list can be modified), and it is not modifying an individual *string* “doing reverse the string” (which isn’t allowed, as strings are immutable).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57152896/15497888) addresses exactly this example complete with helpful info graphics.

Answer (score 2):

`s = s[::-1]` creates a new variable `s` and assigns it to the old variable `s` reversed, leaving the old `s` unchanged. `s[:] = s[::-1]` keeps the same old `s` variable and just mutates its contents with its reversed value. Basically,

```
def f1(s):
    s = s[::-1]

def f2(s):
    s[:] = s[::-1]


s = ["a", "b", "c"]

f1(s)
print(s)    # Outputs ["a", "b", "c"]

f2(s)
print(s)    # Outputs ["c", "b", "a"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Enzo! This made perfect sense!

Comment: In both cases it’s “the *same* variable”. While the official Python parlance might claim to “create a new binding”, *the effect for an existing local variable is to “assign a [different] object to the variable with the given name”* (https://ashtonkemerling.com/posts/binding-vs-assignment/). The call-by-object-sharing nature of Python secondarily explains why this assignment does not affect any bindings (re: variables) in the caller, even if the *same variable [as introduced by an parameter]* is re-assigned.